# Setting up SUID in C language is not enough

Tags: c, security, debian, code-injection

For pedagogical purposes, I want to set up a basic command injection in C. I have the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char cat[] = "cat ";
    char *command;
    size_t commandLength;

    commandLength = strlen(cat) + strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
    command = (char *) malloc(commandLength);

    strncpy(command, cat, commandLength);
    strncat(command, argv[1], (commandLength - strlen(cat)) );

    system(command);
    return (0);
}
```

I compile it, set the binary as owned by root and set the SUID to 1, as follows :

```
gcc injectionos.c -o injectionos
sudo chown root:root injectionos
sudo chmod +s injectionos
```

I obtain the following result :

```
ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 olive olive  4096 Jan  6 13:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 olive olive  4096 Jan  6 12:15 ..
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root  root  16824 Jan  6 13:17 injectionos
-rw-r--r-- 1 olive olive   415 Jan  6 13:17 injectionos.c
-rwx------ 1 root  root      9 Jan  6 12:43 titi.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 olive olive     9 Jan  6 12:16 toto.txt`
```

So, basically, with the SUID set to 1, i should be able to open both toto.txt and titi.txt files by performing the following injection :

```
./injectionos "toto.txt;cat titi.txt"
```

But executing this command, I got a `permission denied` when accessing **titi.txt**. Finally, when I add a `setuid(geteuid());` in my code, the injection is working and I can access to titi.txt file.

Given that injectionos is ran as root and titi.txt belong to root, I supposed that it was enough, but apparently no. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The privileges are being dropped by `/bin/sh` executed as part of the `system()` call. See the man page for bash and the `-p` option

> If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal
> to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no
> startup files are read, shell functions are not inherited from the
> environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE
> variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored, and the
> effective user id is set to the real user id. If the -p option is
> supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the
> effective user id is not reset.

Well, technically debian uses `dash` by default, but it does the same thing.

So the default behavior of the shell has been adjusted to mitigate this injection at least somewhat.

Comment: Note: you can see for yourself that it is the shell doing it by running the whole thing under strace (start as root, `strace -f su - olive` ...)